# Return a JavaScript variable from an external file to a HTML document and then using it within the HTML document

Tags: javascript, return-value

How would I do the above?

I don't really know the correct method for doing it.

I tried the below method:

```
var name;
function welcome(){
    name = prompt("Welcome, what is your name?","Enter name...");
    alert("Hello " + name + ". How are you today?");
    return name;
}
```

and I want to be able to use the returned name value throughout the HTML document.

I tried putting this in the script tags:

```
var name = welcome();
alert(name);
```

The alert doesn't alert name. Also the method is called from a button lower in the HTML code:

```
<button class ="buttonlink"  onclick="'welcome()" >Function</button>
```

Any advice on the correct method would be good :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code has problem with namespace collision, the `name` defined in the external file is overwritten with the `name` on the html when you call `var name` on the HTML page. There are 2 options:

- Quick fix: use another name for it
- Write better code: use [requireJS](http://requirejs.org/) (Javascript module design pattern)

Actually, your code does not return a javascript varible from an external file. Your code in the html and external file are in the same namespace (global window). It's just an illusion that you return a variable from an external file